# How do I make it so next button can't be pressed on keyboard without text?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

Working on an app and wondering how to make it so the next `UIButton` on the `UIKeyboard` cannot be pressed unless text is entered in the `UITextfield`?

Comment: "next"? This means that you have multiple text fields?

Answer (score 0):

Checkmark "Auto-enable Return Key"

[image: Auto-enable Return Key]

Answer (score 0):

You should be implementing `textFieldShouldReturn` in you UITextField Delegate. There you can check whether a valid string has been entered into the text box and allow the next button or not.

[Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:)